# How does Python sort a list of tuples?

Tags: python

Empirically, it seems that Python's default list sorter, when passed a list of tuples, will sort by the first element in each tuple. Is that correct? If not, what's the right way to sort a list of tuples by their first elements?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It automatically sorts a list of tuples by the first elements in the tuples, then by the second elements and so on tuple([1,2,3]) will go before tuple([1,2,4]). If you want to override this behaviour pass a callable as the second argument to the sort method. This callable should return 1, -1, 0.

Comment: Don't use the cmp argument if the key argument to sort will do though!  That is prefer foo.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) to foo.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x[1], y[1])).  It's both easier to understand and much more efficient.

Comment: @cthulahoops I think that using `operator.itemgetter` is in that case better than lambda function : `foo.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))` is nicer than `foo.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`. It's just my opinion though.

Comment: It would be nice to have a relevant link to the documentation though.

Comment: Quite a few years late, but here's from the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#decorate-sort-undecorate): *"... tuples are compared lexicographically; the first items are compared; if they are the same then the second items are compared, and so on."*

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is the default.  In fact, this is the basis of the classic "DSU" ([Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#decorate-sort-undecorate)) idiom in Python.  See [Code Like a Pythonista](https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html).

Comment: 10 years later the link is dead. Is [this](https://samyzaf.com/braude/PYTHON/tutorials/Python_coding_style.pdf) the article? Page 25

Answer (score 9):

No, tuples are [sequence types](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/typesseq.html) just like strings. They are sorted the same, by comparing each element in turn:

```
>>> import random
>>> sorted([(0,0,0,int(random.getrandbits(4))) for x in xrange(10)])
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 4), (0, 0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 0, 7), (0, 0, 0, 8),
(0, 0, 0, 9), (0, 0, 0, 12), (0, 0, 0, 12), (0, 0, 0, 12), (0, 0, 0, 14)]
```

The three zeroes are only there to show that something other than the first element must be getting inspected.

Comment: Hm. I seem to be in the minority ... I don't understand my test results, if Python sorts by only looking at the first element in each tuple.

Comment: It starts with the first item, but then moves on. See Vasil's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the internal list sort method and pass a lambda. If your tuples first element is a integer, this should work.

```
# l is the list of tuples
l.sort(lambda x,y: x-y)
```

You can use any callable for the compare function, not necessarily a lambda. However it needs to return -1 (less than), 0 (equal) or 1 (greater than).

Comment: -1: How will this work with a list of tuples?  I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Comment: The lambda function that will be executed in sort has to have one argument, which is the iteratables element of a tupla serie: pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1]). pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1]) or pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], pair[0]) if you want to have a second layer of order after ordering by the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Devin Jeanpierre" answer to this question [sort-a-dictionary-in-python-by-the-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-dictionary-in-python-by-the-value) where he says to use a tuple and shows how to sort by the second value