# Sorting columns in a table (list of lists) whilst preserving the correspondence of the rows

Tags: python, list, sorting

For example:

```
list1 = ['c', 'b', 'a']
list2 = [3, 2, 1]
list3 = ['11', '10', '01']
table = [list1, list2, list3]
```

I'd like to sort with respect to the first column (list1), but I'd like the final ordering to still preserve the lines (so after sorting I'd still have a line 'b', 2, '10'). In this example I could just sort each list individually but with my data I can't just do that. What's the pythonic approach?

Answer (score 6):

One quick way would be to use `zip`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> transpose = zip(*table)
>>> transpose.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
>>> table = zip(*transpose)
>>> table
[('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3), ('01', '10', '11')]
```

Comment: Riffing a bit on [FMc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542399/sorting-columns-in-a-table-list-of-lists-whilst-preserving-the-correspondence-o/6542819#6542819)'s use of `sorted`, here's a one-liner of the above: `table = zip(*sorted(zip(*table), key=itemgetter(0)))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get a list of indexes (js), sorted by the values in list1.
js = [t[1] for t in sorted((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(list1))]

# Use those indexes to build your new table.
sorted_table = [[row[j] for j in js] for row in table]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644170) for information on how Python sorts a list of tuples.