# convert d-m-Y in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert date from one format to another.Let's say, I have some date:

```
February 27, 1820
April 3, 1885
```

And I want to convert it:

```
27 February 1820
3 April 1885
```

I tried but getting  error:

```
dt = "February 12, 1809" 
dt = datetime.strptime('%d %b %Y')
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [datetime.strptime()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) is all you need.

Comment: Are you really dealing with dates in the 19th century? That's going to create trouble when you want to reformat the date back to readable date using strftime().

Comment: @ Susam Pal: yes, some are before 1900 & some are after 1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday, I learned from Kirk Strauser that **strptime())** is much more slower than other solutions: see [this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814327/sorting-a-tuple-in-python/6814596#comment-8098685)

So my advice is to use another way. For exemple:

```
import re

ss = '''February 27, 1820
a line
April 3, 1885'''

regx = re.compile('(January|February|March|'
                  'April|May|June'
                  'July|August|September|'
                  'October|November|December)'
                  ' '
                  '(\d|[012]\d|3[01])'
                  ',(?= \d{4})')

print regx.findall(ss)
print
print regx.sub('\\2 \\1',ss)
```

### Edit 1

The speed of the program can be improved using **regx.sub(repl,ss)** with **repl()** being a function that doesn't extract the month and day as group(1) and group(2), but by slicing:

```
import re
from time import clock

ss = '''February 27, 1820
a line
April 3, 1885'''

regx = re.compile('(January|February|March|'
                  'April|May|June'
                  'July|August|September|'
                  'October|November|December)'
                  ' '
                  '(\d|[012]\d|3[01])'
                  ',(?= \d{4})')

print regx.findall(ss)
print


te = clock()
for i in xrange(10000):
    x = regx.sub('\\2 \\1',ss)
print clock()-te
print x
print




regx = re.compile('(?:January|February|March|'
                  'April|May|June'
                  'July|August|September|'
                  'October|November|December)'
                  ' '
                  '(?:\d|[012]\d|3[01]),'
                  '(?= \d{4})')

def repl(mat):
    sp = mat.group().split()
    return sp[1][0:-1] + ' ' + sp[0]

te = clock()
for i in xrange(1):
    y = regx.sub(repl,ss)
print clock()-te
print y
```

result

```
[('February', '27'), ('April', '3')]

2.52965614345
27 February 1820
a line
3 April 1885

0.378833622709
27 February 1820
a line
3 April 1885
```

PS: I also knew that there is a problem of span of time covered by strftime and strptime (not before 1900) , that's why I immediately choosed to treat the problem with a regex. People find regexes too heavy and impressive to resort to them, but I don't understand this trend, because as soon as you master just a little the regexes, you can do plenty of things, with efficiency and speed. Hura for the regex tool.

Answer (score 2):

Nor `time.strftime` nor `datetime.datetime.strftime` don't accept year values less then 1900.  So it looks like there is job for `re` (although it is a bad style to use it for such tasks):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'February 27, 1820'
>>> month, day, year = re.findall('(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)', s)[0]  
>>> '%s %s %s' % (day, month, year)
'27 February 1820'
```

Comment: How to get `27 February 1820` by your solution?

Comment: @Liza Simply writing ``'%s %s %s' % (day, month, year)``

Comment: probabaly, `'%s %s %s' % (month, year, day)`. Anyway, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Liza Warning: test the Roman's code on the following string ``'On February 27, 1820 there were 10, 1000, 100000, maybe more shooting stars in the 98, 456347XBC, Hi-Pot galaxy that were seen by 20, 2000 or 200000 persons'`` and you'll see the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use [datetime.datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), or [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/), or [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) to parse your string to date.

Then use [datetime.datetime.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format your datetime object to string using needed format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) / [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('February 27, 1820', '%B %d, %Y')
new_date = date.strftime('%d %b %Y')
```

However, there's one gotcha. `strftime` seems to have problems with years < 1900 on some platforms. There's a [workaround](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/306860-proleptic-gregorian-dates-and-strftime-before-1900/) for it too.