# None-safe comparison for lower-than method

Tags: python

I have several classes with custom `__eq__()` and `__lt__()` methods, to be able to sort the created objects. Here I compare by several, but not all attributes of the objects.

This works great, but now I have to also consider randomly appearing `None` values in the attributes. And it seems like the implicit functionality to compare `None` by `>` was removed in Python 3 (see [Is everything greater than None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214194/is-everything-greater-than-none))

What is the fastest and least noisy method to compare optional values? I don't care if `None` are considered bigger or smaller than the rest.

E.g. a method to compare without considering `None`:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if self.a == other.a:
        return self.b < other.b
    else:
        return self.a < other.a
```

If we now have to also check for `None` in all attributes of both `self` and `other`, how would be the best way? Please keep in mind that the class can have more than the shown two attributes, so a solution like following one is quite noisy and not easy to understand from a glance:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if self.a == other.a:
        return False if other.b is None else (self.b is None or (self.b < other.b))
    else:
        return False if other.a is None else (self.a is None or (self.a < other.a))
```

Comment: Do you need/want the comparisons for anything other than sorting? If not, then sorting with a key function might be better.

Comment: @KellyBundy So far, only for sorting. I just wanted to avoid duplicated code or too many dependencies if there could be an easy in-line solution. But it could be the best way, if no one has a better idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a helper function that focuses on single values:

```
# Assumes T is itself not an Optional type...
def safe_lt[T](x: Optional[T], y: Optional[T]) -> bool:
    """None is smaller than any non-None value"""
    if y is None:
        return False
    elif x is None:
        # y is not None if you reach this
        return True
    else:
        # Neither x nor y is None, compare as usual
        return x < y
```

Then use that in place of bare `<` in your definition:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if self.a == other.a:
        return safe_lt(self.b, other.b)
    else:
        return safe_lt(self.a, other.a)
```

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of creating a function for this, since this explains what happens most easily. But I wanted to look for some "in-line" solutions first, so I don't have to create duplicated code or import something into dozens of files. But if no other solution appears, this might be the best way...

Answer (score 3):

You could compare tuples that contain interleaved "is None" flags for each member:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int | None
    b: int | None

    def __lt__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, Foo):
            return NotImplemented

        return (
            (self.a is not None, self.a),
            (self.b is not None, self.b),
        ) < (
            (other.a is not None, other.a),
            (other.b is not None, other.b),
        )


assert Foo(1, 1) < Foo(1, 2)
assert Foo(None, 1) < Foo(1, 1)
assert Foo(None, 1) < Foo(None, 2)
assert Foo(1, None) < Foo(1, 1)
```

For more complex cases, you can create a helper function to construct the sequences to be compared:

```
def safe_cmp_seq[T](*args: T) -> list[tuple[bool, T]]:
    return [(elem is not None, elem) for elem in args]


class Foo:
    # ...

    def __lt__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, Foo):
            return NotImplemented

        return safe_cmp_seq(self.a, self.b) < safe_cmp_seq(other.a, other.b)
```

Comment: This actually works fine. Although I have to admit that I don't get how this "Is-None-Flag" works during the tuple comparison. It's just a sub-tuple isn't it?
This solution is a bit verbose, but at least somewhat cleaner and easier to adapt for different classes.

Comment: @Asriel See [How does Python sort a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/644170/11082165) and [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#decorate-sort-undecorate) from the Python docs for details on how the tuple comparison works. Using nested tuples is optional, and mostly just help readability by combining related bits. You could also just use a single length-4 tuples with entries in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you (at least so far) only need/want it for sorting, you might be better off with a key function:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: (
    x.a is not None, x.a,
    x.b is not None, x.b
))
```

Logic is the same as Brian's, use `is not None` to first compare `None`-nesses. If they differ, return the proper bool there already. If they're both `None`, then they're equal and the tuple comparison will move on to the next attribute. If they're both *not* `None`, they're compared normally.

Or make the key function a method of the class and then:

```
class Foo:
    def sortkey(self):
        return (
            self.a is not None, self.a,
            self.b is not None, self.b
        )

mylist.sort(key=Foo.sortkey)
```

Or use it to implement `__lt__`:

```
class Foo:
    def sortkey(self):
        return (
            self.a is not None, self.a,
            self.b is not None, self.b
        )
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.sortkey() < other.sortkey()
```

---

Or a different idea: Use an old-style `cmp` function to compare attributes, returning -1/0/1 for smaller/equal/larger, chain them with `or` (this stops comparing at the earliest differing attribute).

```
def cmp(x, y):
    if x is None:
        return 0 if y is None else -1
    if y is None:
        return 1
    return 0 if x == y else -1 if x < y else 1

class Foo:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (
            cmp(self.a, other.a) or
            cmp(self.b, other.b)
        ) < 0
```

A variation with strings instead of numbers:

```
def cmp(x, y):
    if x is None:
        return None if y is None else 'smaller'
    if y is None:
        return 'larger'
    return None if x == y else 'smaller' if x < y else 'larger'

class Foo:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (
            cmp(self.a, other.a) or
            cmp(self.b, other.b)
        ) == 'smaller'
```

Or with "constants":

```
EQUAL, SMALLER, LARGER = 0, 1, 2
def cmp(x, y):
    if x is None:
        return EQUAL if y is None else SMALLER
    if y is None:
        return LARGER
    return EQUAL if x == y else SMALLER if x < y else LARGER

class Foo:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (
            cmp(self.a, other.a) or
            cmp(self.b, other.b)
        ) is SMALLER
```

Comment: I like the old `cmp`-way to compare, although this doesn't seem to bring any benefit in python. Nevertheless, I like the way the last `__lt__()` turned out: Here it's easier to see the order of the sorting priority.

Comment: The only thing I don't like is the very last `< 0`. Without it, it would look a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Asriel I added two more variations, although not sure I like them.